# Kotlin nested multi-generic type class to a Java nested raw type

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, raw-types

When trying to assign a java nested raw type to a kotlin nested generic, the compiler complains about incompatible types

In kotlin I have:
`class ExampleMap : HashMap<String, List<Any>>();`

Now in Java when I try to declare a variable like so `Map<String, List> map = new ExampleMap();`, the compiler complains:

The following however compiles: `Map<String, List<?>> map = new ExampleMap();`. Also when there a single generic type everything works well, i.e. `class ExampleList : ArrayList<Any>() / List list = new ExampleList();`

Is there anyway to do this through an interop between Kotlin and Java? such that `Map<String, List> map = new ExampleMap();` will compile?

Comment: `class ExampleMap : HashMap<String, List<Nothing>>()` for whatever reason this works. I don't understand the detail enough to explain this though. Maybe someone else can help. Just curious, why do you want to use raw type?

Comment: Looks like there is an explanation here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#translation-of-type-nothing. However wanted to avoid using Nothing since I actually want to use an object for the List.
Wanted to use raw type to keep things generic in the consumer of this map

Comment: Can’t you make the consumer side use `List<? extends Object>` or just `List<?>` to “keep it generic”?

Comment: @user3390695 ah that makes sense. Yeah the `Nothing` example was just me goofing around. It is not piratical :P And I agree with Tenfour04, what about List<?>?

Comment: Looks like I have to go that route, but wondering how come it worked when the raw value was not nested 